# Get text from p, not including span values, using Document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have this element structure.

```
<p>
  <span class="ts-aria-only">
  Departure
  </span>
  RUH
  <span class="ts-aria-only">&nbsp;Riyadh</span>
</p>
```

I'm trying to get the text `RUH`, but using `innerText` will return the whole text including the value inside `<span>`.

Some answers posted here on SO uses ajax, which is not applicable for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a text node, so it can't be selected with a query string. You'll have to start from its parent element and access the appropriate `childNodes` index:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('p').childNodes[2].textContent.trim()
);
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="ts-aria-only">
  Departure
  </span>
  RUH
  <span class="ts-aria-only">&nbsp;Riyadh</span>
</p>
```

Comment: I might consider this, but is there a way to directly get the `RUH` inside the p tag without also getting the value inside the spans?

Comment: @cankentcode No there isn't. This is the way to do it.

Comment: I guess you could iterate through all child nodes and only take those which are text nodes, then concatenate them all together and trim them, but that'd be a lot more work

Comment: my bad @CertainPerformance, your snippet works, the `Run code snippet` is returning the original element so I thought it's not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
Array.from(document.querySelector('p').childNodes).reduce((a,b) => a += b.nodeType==3 ? b.textContent.trim() : '' ,'')
```

basically you need to check each childNode if it is textNode (nodeType==3)
then you could do with it whatever you want